# Oracle to MemSql migration

Tags: singlestore

We are running a PoC to migrate a schema from Oracle into MemSql. Looking at the documentation on MemSql site, I could not find any information on how I can migrate server side scripts e.g. pl/sql into MemSql equivalent.

Any pointers regarding this specific point as well as any other tips about moving triggers, views etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://docs.memsql.com/docs/mysql-features-unsupported-in-memsql#section-unsupported-feature-list), PL/SQL, Stored Procedures and triggers are still an unsupported feature in MemSQL.

Information on Views can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.memsql.com/docs/create-view) as well.